# Problem decoding base64 string and saving it as file in flutter

Tags: image, pdf, flutter, base64

I have a chat inside my app where the user can send text messages or 
upload file (jpg and pdf only). For the files, I send them encoded in base64 to the server and I do the conversion on the server side. 
All of the next is already been done:

1. Server gets the base64 string, and save it as an image or a pdf.
2. This files are ok since I can open them from the ftp.
3. The users from the app download the file from the server if they have not already done it (the server returns a base64 encoded string from the file)
4. On the flutter side I get the string and I decode it. And this is where I have the problem:

   - If I use the decoded base64 string directly as an Image.memory(Uint8List) it shows without problem. So the problem has nothing to do with the base64 string.
   - But this is not the behavior that I want since I want the file being 'downloaded' the first time if it does not exist and then if it exists I just want to open it (whit the os default software for image or pdf)

This is the code that I use for saving the file:

```
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
String archivoBase64 = await _repository.getArchivoBase64FromMensaje({'id': data['comentario']['id']});
await File('$dir/${data['comentario']['texto']}').writeAsBytes(base64.decode(archivoBase64).buffer.asUint8List());
await OpenFile.open('$dir/${data['comentario']['texto']}');
```

The `OpenFile.open()`function does what it is expected to do, it shows the software options from the so when it is a pdf or it just shows the image with the so default picture viewer.

IMPORTANT: I use base64 since the files from this chat are private (bills, bank related documents...), so they cannot be accessed from a browser for example since they are in a private folder of the server.

I am using this libraries:

- path_provider: ^0.5.0+1 (for getting paths of files or folders)
- open_file: 1.2.2 (for opening the saved file)

**UPDATE**

I have tried with iOS (iphone 8 iOS 12.2) and with my personal phone (samsung s8plus android 9) and it works perfectly. The phone that I have been trying on is a huawei p8 lite with android 6. I will keep doing more test to see if the error is whit this particular phone, android version, etc.

**UPDATE2**

Somehow I have resolved it. I migrated my flutter project to AndroidX and then updated all my flutter package dependencies to the lastest version. I don't know if that was the thing that solve the problem but now I can open those files from my android 6 device. Hurray!

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Can we see an error log on android 6?

Comment: @tottomotto There is no actual error log on this. The problem is that the conversion from base64 to pdf/jpg and the opening of that file works in android 7 or upper and on iOS. Those files don't open in android 6 or before

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration in case someone else needs it